# MultiChoiceModeListener on listView not working as expected

Tags: android-listview, onclicklistener

I have a listView and setting multiChoiceModeListener on it. It works fine. Now to play an audio item inside the listView I have written

```
ViewHolder.AuidoXmlLayoutItem.setOnClickListener({...playAudioCode...});
```

inside the getView of listView adapter class.

because of this now the multiChoiceModeSelection dosent not show selection of listItem when I longPress on AuidoXmlLayoutItem and hence does not show ContextualActionBar.

How can I keep the onClick of the audio item layout and still allow ContextualActionBar to appear on long click of audio item layout

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `OnItemClickListener` rather than `OnClickListener`. Follow this way,

```
view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

          // playAudioCode
          // change the checkbox state

          ViewToChecked checkedTextView = ((ViewToChecked)view);
          checkedTextView.setChecked(!checkedTextView.isChecked());
     }
 });
```

You might get a concept.